# confused on the combination of Array.isArray() and every()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to check every element within the target object is an array object by using the `every()`function, the code as follows:

```
let targetObj = [[1,2],[3],4];

let result = targetObj.every((val,index,arr)=>{
    return Array.isArray(val);
});
```

the `result`is false because `4` is not an array object, but i found if i replace the callback function with `Array.isArray` which is still work:

```
let result = targetObj.every(Array.isArray);
```

So my questions are:

1.In this way, since the callback function is not taking any parameters.Why the `result` still return `false`?

2.How the `Array.isArray`callback function can automatically check every element from `targetObj`without gave any parameters?

Comment: "*since the callback function is not taking any parameters*" you've made `Array.isArray` into the callback! Which is perfectly valid. No one said you had to use an anonymous function for the callback. Directly passing the function like you did is known as "point-free" programming, you might research it a bit

Answer (score 0):

Array.isArray has one param.
.every( ... ) gives 3 params.

A callback in .every (without calling it directly) is going to give params.
If the callback has more than 3 params, the next params are gonna be undefined.

Since you're not calling the callback, .every is calling it for you and it's gonna fill its params.